# Sublime Text plugin to modify text before it's pasted

Tags: python, plugin, escaping

It's my first plugin and it's *super* simple but there could easily be some things worth knowing from this e.g. Python coding practices and potential bugs.

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class EscapeAndPasteCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, **kwargs):
        # Get the clipboard text
        originalText = textToPaste = sublime.get_clipboard() 
        # Loop through the arguments making changes where possible
        for replacement in kwargs:
            # print("replacing '" + replacement + "'' with '" + kwargs[replacement] + "'")
            textToPaste = textToPaste.replace(replacement,kwargs[replacement])
        # Place the text back into the clipboard and paste in place
        sublime.set_clipboard(textToPaste)
        self.view.run_command("paste")

        # Restore the original text to the clipboard
        sublime.set_clipboard(originalText)
```

The idea is you feed this a dictionary of matches and replacements that it will perform on the clipboard object. Once those changes are made it restores the untouched text to the clipboard.

I made a key binding for this so that when I am pasting text, in my markdown files, that has file paths it will autoescape it for me, such as underscores and slashes that are meant to be just that.

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+v"], 
    "command": "escape_and_paste", 
    "args": {
        "\\": "\\\\",
        "_" : "\\_",
        "*" : "\\*"
    }
}
```

It works well for me and I think I would be lost without it now as it makes my documentation processes easier.

Answer (score 5):

If your intention is to escape certain characters by prefixing them with backslashes, you would be better off with a function that performs that specific task, rather than a generalized function that accepts a dictionary of replacements.

In general, [performing multiple substitution passes over a string is a bad idea](/a/57185/9357).  Certain substitution dictionaries could result in **non-deterministic behaviour**, depending on the order in which the substitutions are performed.  In fact, you have just that problem:

- If the `_` escape is performed before the `\` escape, then `_` would become `\_`, then `\\_`.
- If the `\` escape is performed before the `_` escape, then `_` would remain `_`, then become `\_`.

You *could* overcome that problem by specifying the substitutions using a `collections.OrderedDict`, but I still recommend against it on principle.  Escaping / unescaping is always better done using a single left-to-right pass.

Comment: Yes. That would be a problem.  And I thought this was going to be a silly post. I had initially made a specialized escaping function then thought I could design it so it would be useful in other places. Thanks

Comment: There is also [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate), which avoids this problem.

Comment: I plan on a refactor where you pass all characters you want to escape and the escape character itself. If I were to better this approach does left to right mean that I do all changes one character at a time and loop through the string

Comment: You could do that, or the regex substitution in the answer that I cited. The best solution is probably `str.translate()` as suggested by @Graipher.

Comment: Sorry to bug you about this but this is what I ended up doing and its not worth another question `textToPaste = textToPaste.translate(str.maketrans(kwargs))`. Converted my arguments to a translation map outright. I think that should prevent any issues.

Comment: That should work, I think.